# Android get custom table row in the asynctask

Tags: android, android-layout

Is this possible to get some `TableRow` which is in XML layout, from `AsyncTask`?
I just need to get bitmap of it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/APs_layout"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff57200">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/Aps_header_table_Row1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView41"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:text="SSID"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView42"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="channel"/>
        <!--TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView43"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="STRENTH"/-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_wifi_bars"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView44"
            android:layout_width="70px"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="quality"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView45"
            android:layout_width="75px"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="  signal"/>
        <!--TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView46"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="SECURITY"/-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_width="30px"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_wifi_lock"/>           
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView47"
            android:layout_width="97px"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="mode     "/>
        <!--TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView47"
            android:layout_width="90px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="band"/-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_wifiabgn" 
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:layout_width="30px"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView47"
            android:layout_width="150px"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="mac"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_networks_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/controls"
    android:layout_below ="@id/table1"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="false"

    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
<include
    android:id="@+id/controls"
    layout="@layout/buttons_bottom_with_relative" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just need to grab the view of the header(Aps_header_table_Row1). Later I will extract  the Bitmap of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this XML is not already loaded as your activity's contentview (From setContentView), you can inflate it using a layoutInflater:

```
RelativeLayout layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.thisXmlFileName);
```

Then just get the view by it's ID:

```
TextView header = (TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.Aps_header_table_Row1)
```

Comment: any ideas how to getLayoutInflater() from AsyncTask?

Comment: I couldn't figure out formatting in a comment, so see my other answer

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference of your context to an AsyncTask:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<?, ? ,?> {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    } 
}
```

set up your asyncTask using this new constructor:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(this);
task.execute(...);
```

Then you can access the context to get the layout inflater from within the asynctask:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
```